# How does the events dispatcher map to map_save to a callback function?

Tags: 8

MigrateEvents.php contains an event definition like this:

```
/**
 * Name of the event fired when saving to a migration's map.
 *
 * This event allows modules to perform an action whenever the disposition of
 * an item being migrated is saved to the map table. The event listener method
 * receives a \Drupal\migrate\Event\MigrateMapSaveEvent instance.
 *
 * @Event
 *
 * @see \Drupal\migrate\Event\MigrateMapSaveEvent
 *
 * @var string
 */
const MAP_SAVE = 'migrate.map_save';
```

If I grep the codebase for `map_save`, there is no other reference to it. What mechanism does Drupal/Symfony use to know the callback to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@larowlan indicates the correct way to implement a subscriber; however, the original question asks about how map_save is called, and the two examples in core and contrib both call the addListener method directly.

From Core [MigrateEventsTest](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Tests%21MigrateEventsTest.php/8):

```
\Drupal::service('event_dispatcher')->addListener(MigrateEvents::MAP_SAVE, array($this, 'mapSaveEventRecorder'));
```

From [migrate_tools](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/migrate_tools/tree/src/MigrateExecutable.php#n100):

```
$this->listeners[MigrateEvents::MAP_SAVE] = [$this, 'onMapSave'];
...
foreach ($this->listeners as $event => $listener) {
    \Drupal::service('event_dispatcher')->addListener($event, $listener);
}
```

According to the [Drupal 8 services documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2133171) this is not the recommended approach. Use the services container to ensure decoupled and testable code.

Comment: To clarify: The approach not recommended pertains to the whole answer or just the static Drupal instance?

Answer (score 3):

This event is fired by `\Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\id_map\Sql::saveIdMapping()`.

```
$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(MigrateEvents::MAP_SAVE, new MigrateMapSaveEvent($this, $keys + $fields));
```

To listen and react to this event you need to add a new service that implements `\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface` and tag it with 'event_subscriber'.

This is what you find in content_translation.services.yml.

```
content_translation.updates_manager:
  class: Drupal\content_translation\ContentTranslationUpdatesManager
    arguments: ['@entity.manager', '@entity.definition_update_manager']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

This tells the event dispatcher the `ContentTranslationUpdatesManager` class subscribes to events.

When you look at `\Drupal\content_translation\ContentTranslationUpdatesManager::getSubscribedEvents()` you can see that it subscribes to the `\Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigEvents::IMPORT` event and when this event fires, the `\Drupal\content_translation\ContentTranslationUpdatesManager::onConfigImporterImport()` method should fire, with a priority of 60. Note that priority works in reverse to the typical Drupal weight: This listener goes before those with a lower priority and after those with a higher priority.

You can read about the generic event dispatcher in the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html).

The Drupal relevant bit here is the event_subscriber tag, which is processed in a compiler pass by `\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterEventSubscribersPass::process()`, taking care of the [registering of listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#connecting-listeners) automatically, based on the presence of that tag.

Comment: Elaborated some more to include the compiler pass, which is the Drupal-specific bits, the rest is applicable to any other project that uses the event-dispatcher component

Comment: Adding for further reference: [MigrateEventsTest](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Tests%21MigrateEventsTest.php/class/MigrateEventsTest/8)